# Trying to create a well count to compare to BOE using the on production date and comparing it to Capital spends and total BOE

Tags: sql, spotfire

I have data that includes the below columns:

```
Date
Total Capital
Total BOED
On Production Date
UWI
```

I'm trying to create a well count based on the unique UWI for each On Production Date and graph it against the Total BOED/Total Capital with Date as the x-axis.

I've tried unique count by UWI but it then populates ALL rows of that UWI with the same well count total, so when it is summed the numbers are multiplied by the row count.

Plot Xaxis as Date and Y with Total BOED and Well Count.

Comment: Make sure to show the community what you've tried. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for assistance.

Answer (score 0):

Add a calculated column to create a row id using the rowid() function.  Then, in the calculation you already have, the one that populates all rows of the UWI with the same well count, add the following logic...

if([rowid] = min([rowid]) over [UWI], uniquecount([UWI]) over [Production Date], null)

This will make it so that the count only populates once.